# Does memoized callbacks change only if their dependencies are part of the state?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, memoization

I got a React memoized callback which is using a value from a redux store:

```
const filterValue = useSelector(state => state.filterValue);
const filter = useCallback(
item =>
  includes(item.name.toLowerCase(), filterValue.toLowerCase()) ||
  includes(item.description.toLowerCase(), filterValue.toLowerCase()),
[filterValue]);
```

My question is if the memoized callback will actually be rerendered only when `filterValue` changes, or do I have to set filterValue as the components state instead from the redux store (meaning `const [filterValue, setFilterValue] = useState('');`) in order for the change in dependency to be detected?

Comment: It will be re-rendered whenever `filterValue` changes.
`filterValue` does not have to necessarily come though `useState`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be rerendered only when `filterValue` changes.

If you wonder why, you can peak [`useSelector` implementation](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/2a5b12bd95ddc8e0550ae6546f71ddbf0156d43f/src/hooks/useSelector.js#L102) and see [`useReduxContext`](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/2a5b12bd95ddc8e0550ae6546f71ddbf0156d43f/src/hooks/useReduxContext.js#L20) is called by Context API.

That means that the state `filterValue` which was selected by `useSelector` is a part of components state like when you use `useState`, therefore it legitimate value for `useEffect`'s dependency array.